# How can I make HDR images without the cartoon look?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, hdr, exposure-fusion

I am processing some photos intended to show HDR and I mainly want to bring out all the tones of a scene, which is why I took three bracketed shots to begin with.

But pushing the detail pretty quickly turns it into the bright "disneyland" acid trip that got really popular on flickr a few years ago. That sort of thing has its place, but it's not what I'm going for right now

What's a good workflow for using bracketed exposures and using them to create another photograph that simply has better exposure? I'm going for subtle not "wow colors!1!1!!! join my hdr stream!"

Currently just selected my three exposures in Lightroom and clicked "edit in HDR Pro in Photoshop"

I'm not sure what the current tools are for HDR, either. I remember reading about avoiding these automated things because they are not "true HDR" or something about tonemapping. That's great; now how do I use some good tools to get the dynamic range I'm looking for?

With HDRPro in Photoshop, 32bit mode seems to be automatically creating results closer to what I imagine. But this doesn't give me any latitude to adjust exposure, etc., before further processing.

Comment: Do you use the photorealistic presets in HDR Pro?

Comment: I'm not familiar with them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What you are looking for [Exposure Fusion](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/exposure-fusion-what-is-it-how-does-it-compare-to-hdr-how-do-i-do-it) not HDR.**

This averages out pixels from different exposures to produce directly a low-dynamic-range image, so there is not need to do the tone-mapping like for HDR images. Tone-mapping is the delicate operation where, without a subtle hand, you end up with the types of images you are talking about.

Comment: Since you're working in Lightroom, see [LR/Enfuse](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrenfuse.php) for an exposure fusion tool that integrates with LR.

Comment: Itai, coneslayer, this is amazing and exactly what I was looking for. Glad to see that bracketed image stacking has evolved!

Comment: Whilst exactly what they're after, I'd argue that the guy writing that article is wrong when he says it's not HDR. It is exactly what HDR was meant to be originally, until people started confusing crazy tone mapping with HDR. So now people confuse crazy tone mapping (or that cartoony look) with how HDR should look and think this fusion is somehow different

Comment: @Dreamager Exposure fusion produces a LDR output from multiple LDR inputs. There's never a HDR representation of the scene, as there is in true HDR processing (prior to tone mapping). I think you're looking at it from the standpoint of "capturing a scene with a large dynamic range," while the author is looking at it from the perspective of intermediaries and outputs produced. See for example http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~tmertens/papers/exposure_fusion_reduced.pdf

Comment: But that's what HDR is. It's taking lots of normal exposures to combine them to create a high dynamic range to work from to create a standard dynamic range (or ldr) picture that has used info from the higher range. Tone mapping is just one of the ways of controlling how the output picture looks and the extreme tone mapping is what everyone has come to assume is HDR. This fusion method still uses the high dynamic range of the scene to produce the output image, so is HDR. It just doesn't have a tone mapped representation to play with that people would normally associate with HDR processing

Comment: @Dreamager You said "HDR is ... taking lots of normal exposures to combine them to create a high dynamic range to work from". That's my point: Exposure fusion doesn't do that. There is no HDR representation of the scene at any point in the exposure fusion process. Exposure fusion is algorithmically distinct from both HDR generation and tone mapping, or the combination of the two.

Comment: HDR images have a lot of use outside of photography where they are used to produce very realistic rendering of scenes and interactive environments. With photography our limitation of using mediums of low dynamic range (print/display) means that one can only show a small slice of dynamic range at a time and this what the tone-mapping process is for. Exposure Fusion goes directly from LDR to LDR.

Comment: But a collection of bracketed LDR source material is HDR data. The algorithm process that combines them all is the HDR element between the LDR input and the LDR output. It is just not a part of the process that is visually manipulative like tone mapping sliders in something like photoshop, but the HDR data and element is still there, the 'fusion' just takes care of all the work for you. It's just an alternative way of utlising HDR to the normal tone mapping method people associate with it.

Comment: @Dreamager: In exposure fusion, there is no "HDR element between the LDR input and the LDR output". I'm not merely saying "it's not presented to the user" or "it's not written to a file". It *does not exist* as a data structure at any point in the exposure fusion process, period.

Comment: EF is a simple filter function compared to HDR. See here for a direct comparsion between EF and HDR: http://www.digital-photography-school.com/exposure-fusion-what-is-it-how-does-it-compare-to-hdr-how-do-i-do-it The EF seems to be giving a result that is slightly more "contrast overload" than HDR, so the OP might actually be looking for a HDR process after all.

Comment: Having multiple LDR shots makes HDR data though... that's how it's able to fuse them into a more dynamic shot

Comment: @Dreamager: I would say that multiple LDR shots *contain the information necessary* to create HDR data, but until you linearize and combine the LDR shots based on the camera calibration and relative exposure, you don't *have* HDR data per se. Exposure fusion does not perform this step; instead it directly compares pixel values in the non-adjusted LDR space.

Comment: In my brain that just seems a different way of creating hDR. The steps are different but the data drawn from is still a high dynamic range. The only way I see the exposure fusion not counting as HDR is if somebody has taken a single RAW file and extracted different bracketed shots for the LDR input like some people do for pseudo HDR tone-mapped images. Whether it's tone mapping, or exposure fusion, my brain just can't see them as anything other than different ways of using HDR :D

Comment: @Dreamager: One way that really makes EF seem different from HDR to me is that EF can use pixel quality metrics _other than_ exposure for selecting pixels. So you can do "EF" based on saturation or sharpness instead of exposure simply by changing the quality metric. Or you can, say, combine exposure and saturation into a single quality metric. That's a concept that you can't really relate to HDR processing, which really is based on the idea of reconstructing the light intensity in the original scene onto a linear scale, and manipulating it from there.

Comment: Definitely some interesting applications of exposure fusion, I'll have to check them out as I've been meaning to do more macro shots. Whilst exposure fusion can do more than just HDR, the fusion of exposures still seems to be HDR to me

Comment: I think what you are really discussing is the definition of "HDR". **The term *High Dynamic Range* has been around for a long time with a much broader definition than what most of us today mean when we use it to describe a 32 bit floating point digital image.** Gustave Le Gray first combined two disparately exposed negatives of the same scene into one print in 1850. The products of dodging and burning B&W images in the darkroom were referred to as High Dynamic Range Images at the time Ansel Adams perfected those techniques. **At its broadest, "HDR" means any method of contrast reduction.**

Comment: unless they do all their calculations in 8bit space, it is HDR. even the equation is the same as HDR except they leave out the exposure factor in the weighting. This has some implications which Ive seen myself when I made my own hdr functions and tried to leave out the exposure wight as well. the benefit is that of local contrast enhancement, but you also cannot see the difference between a twice as bright thing captured at half the exposure. They do have some interesting approaches to overcoming some artifacts I saw, but it is way too slow.

Comment: Also Halcon imaging library's HDR function that is based on fusing the contrast and then reconstructing the intensities is way too slow. And then you have the "real" HDr where you build up the ladder and have to squeeze it back under the short roof. Fast, physically correct, but you need some tricks to keep the contrast. But it is really the same that goes on when cooking your raw file, and people just need to hold back their trigger happy fingers to keep it natural.