# What Software Exists to Perform Exposure-Fusion?

Tags: software, exposure-fusion

*Now that Exposure-Fusion is gaining interest, we should have list of current Exposure-Fusion software and plugins.*

**What software options exist to perform Exposure-Fusion?** For applications, please indicate which platform it is available for (Windows, Linux, Mac) and for plugins which application it requires (Photoshop, Lightroom, Corel Photo Paint, etc). Also, it would be good to know if the software is free, open-source or commercial.

If you have experience with a particular software, then any observation on its ease of use, quality of its output and performance would be very welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exposure Fusion Software:

- [Enfuse](http://wiki.panotools.org/Enfuse) - Enfuse merges different exposures of the same scene to produce an image that looks much like a tone-mapped image. Standalone command line tool, open-source, Windows, OSX, Linux compatible.
- [LR/Enfuse](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrenfuse.php) - Plugin for Lightroom that uses Enfuse, Windows, OSX compatible.
- [Hugin](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin) - Integrates Enfuse fully, Windows, OS X, Linux compatible.
- [Photomatix Pro](http://www.hdrsoft.com/) - Standalone or as a plugin for Lightroom, Aperture or Photoshop, Commercial, Windows and OSX compatible.
- [PTGui](http://www.ptgui.com) - Originally designed for creating panoramas but you can make it work for fusion, Windows and OSX compatible.
- [EnfuseGUI](http://software.bergmark.com/enfuseGUI/Main.html) - EnfuseGUI is a front-end for Enfuse, making the process of blending your images easier, Windows and OSX compatible.
- [EnBlend](http://enblend.sourceforge.net/) - Enblend blends away the seams in a panoramic image mosaic using a multi-resolution spline. Command line utility, Windows.
- [Braketeer](http://www.pangeasoft.net/pano/bracketeer/index.html) - Graphical front end for Enfuse, commercial, OSX compatible.

Comment: Can you note the difference between the first and last one?

Comment: @Itai - I pulled some clarification from the sourceforge pages. Let me know if you were looking for more.

Answer (score 3):

[Photomatix](http://www.hdrsoft.com/) seems to be the most favored HDR program.  There is a free trial.  After the trial expires, you can continue to use it, but will have a watermark on the images (although some tone mapping and exposure fusion methods do not print a watermark).

Photomatix excels at alignment and ghosting compared to other HDR programs I've used (Nik and Oloneo).  I find Nik slightly easier to use as far as sliders and presets are concerned, but photomatix will have far more tutorials and resources online, as it has been heavily favored by bloggers for years.