# What settings do I need for shooting a candid against the sky?

Tags: exposure, autofocus, metering, sky, backlight

I have Canon 1000D. Most of the times I use canon 50MM F1.8.

I use evaluative metering and single point (center) auto focus.

What setting do I need to change to have metering of sky (say red of evening), while keeping subject on road well in focus and well exposed?

I don't want to use flash at all...

Comment: I think AE Lock will do what I want. Sorry to say, but I don't like multiple exposure and heavy post processing. (No offence, its just a matter of personal choice :D).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Hasin is correct. Bracket the shots and then apply photorealistic HDR techniques. Here's my final shot:

[image]

This was three exposures of 0.4, 0.1 and 1.6 seconds at f4.0, ISO 100. If you bump your ISO you can use much shorter exposures. I don't like doing that since it introduces noise which HDR can really magnify. Of course I used a tripod.

(The lens was the Canon 17-40mm set to 17mm mounted on a Canon 40D body.)

The camera was set to pattern metering, which is probably better than spot metering for a bracketed situation. I don't see the focus recorded in the EXIF data but I almost always shoot with manual focus. Stationary subjects really help here!

Now, what type of subject are you intending to have in the foreground? A person? If so, be careful. HDR can make faces look awful. You might need to take your HDR final and bring it into Photoshop, then layer the overexposed bracket on top of it, and brush away all so the overexposed bracket face (which will be correctly exposed) comes through.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you take bracketed shots and merge them using Exposure Fusion technique, it may work.

here is a link: [How does exposure fusion work?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-does-exposure-fusion-work)