# What is the best practice in using LR/Enfuse?

Tags: post-processing, hdr, dynamic-range, lightroom-4, exposure-fusion

I have Lightroom 4 and have downloaded LR/Enfuse for Mac.

I have checked out the information on using Enfuse but with my endeavours are not that happy with the results.  That is I was expecting a more of a dynamic range than I have received - The images do not look that much different prior to the enfused images.

Could anybody give me some tips to achieve the dynamic range I am looking for.  I am not expecting a  HDR that one might get with photomatix etc.

thank you

Comment: Can you post a few examples of what you've tried and the results you're not happy with?

Comment: Maybe its not a software problem... This combination works for me out-of-the-box. Try wider increments for your brackets. Usually 4 stops apart is a good start.

Comment: What kind of photos are you taking (nature/landscapes, interior/architecture, indoor where you need to see what's outside the windows, exterior house where you need to inside through the windows), and how many exposures are you taking for each series?

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting exposure fusion or HDR results? See: [How does exposure fusion work?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-does-exposure-fusion-work)

LR/Enfuse uses Enfuse which merges exposures but does not create an HDR image.

This is an example of an image that used exposure fusion:
[image: After exposure fusion and lightroom]

This is an example of an image that was output from an HDR image and tone mapped:
[image: HDR after tonemapping]

Answer (score 1):

I use enfuse for interior photography.  I often find that you need to increase the fill and recovery sliders (LR3) before running enfuse.

See the following images, first image is the final enfused image followed by 3 brackets 0/-2/+2

[image]