# Canon Rebel SL1 using timer, taking multiple photos

Tags: canon

I’m trying to take a single photo with my Rebel SL1 on Manual mode. Here are a some of the issues I’m seeing while on Manual mode:

1. It takes 5 photos per single hard press of the shutter button. The resulting photos vary in brightness.
2. When I take a photo the display screen reads “self-timer is on. Touch the screen to cancel”
3. With a light press of the shutter button, the “Driver/self-timer mode” on the display screen changes from “Single shooting” mode to “Self-timer:2 sec” mode.

Ive tried the classic troubleshooting tactics - clearing the camera settings, clearing custom functions, removing and reinserting the battery. None of these resolved the issue or changed the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It takes 5 photos per single hard press of the shutter button. The resulting photos vary in brightness.

That sounds like you've got exposure bracketing enabled. However, the [*EOS Rebel SL1/100D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010915/01/eos-rebelsl1-100d-im-en.pdf) indicates that the Rebel SL1 only brackets for three exposures. There are other Canon advanced models that allow five and even seven exposure sets of bracketed shots.

I'd check to see what firmware version the camera indicates is installed. Is it possible the firmware for a different Canon model got installed to your SL1? If so, I'd expect all kinds of weird bugs and glitchy behavior such as you are describing.

My advice would be to update to the most current version of the **EOS SL1/100D** firmware downloaded directly from the Canon website for you world region.

Comment: While it wasn't a firmware issue, trying to update the firmware helped me solve the problem. I received the camera from a friend and it had some 3rd party software installed on it (Magic Lantern). Once I uninstalled/disabled this software the camera worked as described in the instructions.

Comment: I've always been under the impression that all one has to do to disable ML is use another memory card that doesn't have ML loaded on it.

Comment: It sounds like a wrong version of ML for that camera may have been in play.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m trying to take a single photo with my Rebel SL1 on Manual mode.

Manual mode only controls exposure settings. What you're describing involves [**the drive mode**](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010915/01/eos-rebelsl1-100d-im-en.pdf#page=108): how pressing the shutter button activates the shutter mechanism: single shot, continuous burst, or on a timer delay.

> It takes 5 photos per single hard press of the shutter button. The resulting photos vary in brightness.

This means you have [auto exposure bracketing (AEB) set](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010915/01/eos-rebelsl1-100d-im-en.pdf#page=125). The camera takes multiple frames and varies the exposure. Most shooters use this mode if they're unsure of proper exposure, or to use a set of frames for exposure stacking techniques like [HDR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/what-is-hdr-photography) or [exposure fusion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-does-exposure-fusion-work).

The timer warning and five shots in the bursts also indicates that your drive mode is set as [the 10-second self-timer plus continuous shots mode](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010915/01/eos-rebelsl1-100d-im-en.pdf#page=110), and set the number of images taken to five.

To turn off AEB:

1. In the menus, select [**camera 2 tab**] → **Expo. comp/AEB**.
2. Press **SET**.
3. Use the control wheel and the right/left buttons, to turn bracketing off (you only have the single indicator at 0).
4. Press **SET**.

To select a different drive mode:

1. In the menus select [**camera 1 tab**] → **Drive/self timer**.
2. Press **SET**.
3. Select the drive mode you do want:

   [image: screencap from manual page describing drive mode icons]

Comment: The camera in question does not have an option for five frames in AEB mode, only three. It seems an incorrect version of Magic Lantern was the culprit.

Comment: @MichaelC, if you read the manual page I linked to, there is an option with the continuous burst mode to program the number of shots to more than 3: "Press the [up] and [down] keys to set the number of multiple shots (2 to 10) to be taken with the self timer." Yes. It's clear now he had some MagicLantern bracketing mode set, but that information wasn't given at the time I answered. And I figure this might still be a useful answer for someone googling five years from now.

Comment: Compare the SL1/100D manual to page 484 (p.486 in the Adobe reader's numbering) of the [5D Mark IV Manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300024970/01/eos5d-mk4-im-en.pdf#page=486) that allows for more than three bracketed exposures. There's no corresponding menu option for the SL1/100D.

Comment: Page126 of the SL1/100D manual clarifies that when continuous self-timer is selected and AEB is active, you will get a full series of three bracketed exposures for each of the number displayed per page 110. In other words, if you select "5" in the 'Self-timer: Continuous' menu, you'll get five *sets* of three bracketed images, but they'll all be based on the same "Standard" exposure with one "0", one "-" and one "+" frame in each series.

Comment: Also, please [compare the Canon published specifications](https://imgur.com/a/Qn8exLb) of the 5D Mark III (on the left) compared to the Rebel SL1/100D (on the right).