# HDR, exposure fusion, high dynamic range, iPhone

Tags: hdr, iphone, exposure-fusion

I’m not a photographer but I sometimes take pictures with a phone. As I understand, HDR mode in IPhone’s camera (I have iPhone 5) expands the number of values in a photograph by merging several exposures. Even though it does exactly what I want I still suspect it’s capable of even more, because when I slide the exposure slider to the very bottom, setting it to the lowest exposure possible, the brightest values are revealed a lot more than in the HDR mode. So, what I would want to find is a mechanical, automatic way to create a gradient of photographs from the lowest exposure possible to the highest and fuse them together. It may be an app or computer software. I think it’s an easy thing to do for an iPhone, the only thing that's missing is the automaticity of it. I can only do it by hand: taking multiple pictures at different exposures. Although, maybe I’m confused and HDR mode is already doing that and it is indeed the most it can do.

I'm attaching a group of photos I took with different exposures and an HDR one.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-does-exposure-fusion-work?rq=1

Comment: There is nothing about an automatic, precise way of taking the shots. I posted this question exactly because I've read the most I could and didn't find an answer to it. What I need is something that digitally uses the exposure intensity so that there wouldn't be a human factor that comes with the manual setting of exposure brackets. I also need it because I would want to see the result on the spot. I need to compare it to the scene as my eye sees it. Although I think immediate exposure fusion is too much to ask from a mobile application, that's why I didn't really mention it in the question.

Comment: The only way to do this in what appears to be a single shot is with a newer, smarter iPhone. For everything else, there's exposure bracketing & post-process. Many higher range cameras can take predetermined bracket sets from a single button-push. That's what I see the FX guys on movie sets doing when they're mapping the location for CGI. I can't see the settings, but I hear 7 exposures every time. [I don't actually work on the camera side of things] Presumably this is from 'far too dark' to 'far too light' so they don't have to change it each time.

Comment: Damn, to me this seems like such a simplistic thing. Surprising no one made such an app. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There are [or were] plenty of iPhone apps, but the iPhone's built-in structure is now really very good, which scared a lot of them off. Unfortunately, it wasn't so good back when the iPhone 5 was around.